# Pause MS Flow until specific HTTP request is sent

Tags: power-automate

I was wondering if there is a simple way to pause MS Flow until a specific HTTP request is received? I'm trying to to do the following:

Flow starts on MS Forms (Submit) >> Send email to a specific user with a link to "approve or cancel" >> on approve continue the flow to next step or ON Cancel, cancel the flow.

Would it be best to create two separate flow, the second one triggers on the first complete?

Comment: Check out approval workflow, this is what it does. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/modern-approvals, and https://www.bulb.digital/blog/email-with-options-vs-built-in-approvals-in-power-automate

Comment: This is the literal definition of approvals.

Comment: If you have restrictions where you can only send the approval workflow to your company domain only, but you whishes to capture external user response too then you can try out **Send Email With Options** - https://www.spguides.com/send-an-email-with-options-in-power-automate/